# List comprehension to identify string matches between two lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm using list comprehension to filter strings in `list_a` (a large list) that contain any of the strings in `list_b` (another large list). I've been able to successfully use the code below to generate a list of the items in list_a that have such matches:

```
list_a_results = [s for s in list_a if any(xs in s for xs in list_b)]
```

Now I'm trying to do what I'm thinking of as the reverse process, ie, identify each of the items from `list_b` that show up in each string listed in `list_a_results`. Is there a nifty way to use list comprehension to achieve this?

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish: when given:

```
list_a_results = ['abc def ghi jkl', 'mno pqr', 'stu', 'vwx yz']
list_b = ['abc', 'ghi', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']
```

I want to be able to generate the following:

```
matches_in_list_a = [['abc', 'ghi'], 'pqr', 'stu', ['vwx','yz']]
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here. Are you looking for `list_b_results = [b for b in list_b if any(b in a for a in list_a_results)]`? There's likely a more efficient solution, but it's hard to tell without a concrete example.

Comment: @pault Just added an example - lmk if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much a verbatim solution: for each element b of B, each element a of A s.t. a is in b.

```
# constant depth result
res = [[s for s in list_b if s in a] for a in list_a_results]
# [['abc', 'ghi'], ['pqr'], ['stu'], ['vwx', 'yz']]

# desired output
itr = ([s for s in list_b if s in a] for a in list_a_results)
res2 = [x.pop() if len(x) == 1 else x for x in itr]
# [['abc', 'ghi'], 'pqr', 'stu', ['vwx', 'yz']]
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion, I'd been interpreting the list comprehension incorrectly and this cleared it up.